# Migrating Relational to Multidimensional - How to Create Time Dimension from Timestamp - SSAS

Tags: ssas, etl, dimensional-modeling

**Objective:** I have a relational database(RDB) model. A few tables have an attribute timestamp. 
I want to create a date dimension for my multidimensional model.

Viewing the [Microsoft Tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/multidimensional-modeling-adventure-works-tutorial) Solution 3, I noticed that the time Date dimension table's attribute FullDateAlternateKey has the same format as the timestamp attribute in the RDB's tables.

**Question:** So, I was wondering if there is a way to automatically generate a Date dimension table schema (with the FullDateAlternateKey as primary key) and populate it with the data from the timestamps in the RDB's tables?

Then I could make the timestamp attribute from the RDB's tables a foreign key to the Time dimension table in my multidimensional model.

Answer (score 2):

Don't.

First, decide the "grain" of your dimension. It sounds like you want a DATE dimension, so the grain will be a day.

Then, decide the columns you want in the dimension. Examples are week number, day number in week, day number in year, day name, month name, etc.

Next, build a spreadsheet that contains one row per date, for the range of dates you need, and calculates the columns you require.

Finally, load and process the dimension, from the spreadsheet, using your preferred ETL/ELT method.

The reason you don't build it from the incoming data values is that you may have gaps in the data. A date dimension should have ALL dates in your desired range (ie, 1900-01-01 to 2999-12-31) so that your BI tools can eventually use it for time series reporting. If you don't have ALL the dates, and try to show date on the x-axis of a graph, you will get misrepresentative visualisations.

Another reason for using a spreadsheet as your source is that the DATE dimension is one of the most volatile dimensions in your design. Your users will ask for new columns, and variations on columns (ie, "Can we have a column with the date like 4th. of August, 2017?") and a spreadsheet is a very fast way to manage the data, and rebuild the dimension when necessary.

Comment: What about the data that is already in the database? How is it going to match the time dimension? That is my problem/doubt. 

I need to show the data that comes from a relational database, so I need a way to convert the timestamp attribute of those relational tables into date dimension, so that I can show those tables. Or not?

Comment: I don't know your load process, so I can't pinpoint just one solution, but a working option would be to add a DATE column to your fact table, and populate it with your timestamp cast to a date. Then, if you have your date dimension keyed by date, you can join the two tables.

Answer (score -1):

Step 1:
Choose granularity and generate time dimension key based on that granularity. For example, choosing the granularity hour, one would need something like 2001020323 (yyyymmddhh).

There is no automatic way to do this using SSAS, so it's best to use a script to build the time dimension table in the underlying data source, then import it to DSV in SSAS and use it to build the time dimension. ([like this one](http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.pt/2011/01/create-and-fill-time-dimension.html))

Step 2: 
I have to match the time dimension's keys, so I need an ETL process/job/script taking my timestamp as input and returning a key for that timestamp that matches the keys in the time dimension table.

Comment: A dimension that just has timestamps that are used in the facts isn't useful as a time/date dimension- it needs to be a continuous dimension of dates or times, including those not used as per Ron's answer. You certainly would be able to create a dimension from your fact's timestamps, by querying that in the DSV, but Ron's right: don't.

Comment: I have to match the time dimension's keys, hence why I need the ETL on my timestamp.

Comment: Of course. But your time dimension should be made independently of what is in your fact, and then you match to that.